# How to see if a struct in struct pointer contains an element

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, struct

I have a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct ltsaNode {
   int call;
   int action;
   ltsaNode *nextActions;
   ltsaNode *sibling;
} ltsaNode;
```

And a struct pointer `*wanted` and an `int i`

I want to check if any of the structs in `wanted` has `call` equal to `i`.

My current solution:

```
BOOL a = FALSE;
for(;wanted!= NULL;wanted->sibling)
{
    if(wanted->call == i)
    {
        a=TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better or faster way to do this ?

Comment: You start with some value of wanted. You keep looping as long as wanted is different from NULL. At each iteration, you _increment_ wanted. Good luck waiting for it to become NULL.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Edited the code. Added siblings for the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for I guess.

```
BOOL a = FALSE;
for(; wanted != NULL; wanted = wanted->sibling)
{
    if(wanted->call == i)
    {
        a = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, however I do not want to loop over nextActions. wanted becomes nextActions after the call has been found and the action has been used.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information to understand that pointers to your structs are stored in an array. It is also not clear what you want to do when you find a struct with `call == i`. I hope my answer helped anyway.

Comment: @chmike Your awnser helped to refactor the code. I added sibling to loop over

Comment: Ok. I saw the sibling field. Be aware that you have to write `wanted = wanted->sibling`. Writing `wanted->sibling` alone will do nothing.